# How does a Laravel factory gets the $factory variable defined?

Tags: php, laravel, factory

A new factory in laravel looks like this;

```
<?php

/* @var $factory \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factory */

use App\Model;
use Faker\Generator as Faker;

$factory->define(Model::class, function (Faker $faker) {
    return [
        //
    ];
});
```

The variabele `$factory` does'nt get defined in this file. How and where does this variabele get defined? A `dd($factory)` results as expected in an `\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factory` object

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The variable `$factory` is not defined in the file itself. Only when this file is processed by Laravel, by including it during the loading process, is that $factory will reference the Factory object.

This is where factory files get loaded: [\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factory::load](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/0b12ef19623c40e22eff91a4b48cb13b3b415b25/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Factory.php#L214)

Note the docblock at the beginning of the factory file, it's there to help your IDE with auto-completion:

```
/** @var \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factory $factory */
```

Now you might wonder where `Factory::load()` first gets called. It gets called when the Factory is first instantiated by the DI container, once you use the [factory()](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/0b12ef19623c40e22eff91a4b48cb13b3b415b25/src/Illuminate/Foundation/helpers.php#L487) helper for instance.

Comment: When and how does this load-function get called?

Comment: Still don't get it, where does factory() come from then? I looked at the list of service providers in app.php, only DatabaseServiceProvider gets loaded there, which doesn't register a $factory as far as I can see

Comment: The factory() helper function is defined in the helpers.php file. There is a link to it in the answer.